# NIS: How to allow access to both local and remote users' home directories?

Tags: mount, users, nis

We have a NIS server with shared users' home directories in '/home'.

We're used to mounting the server's '/home' using '/home' as the mount point on each NIS client.

However, if we do this with a machine that has existing local users, their home directories will not be accessible because '/home' is now a mount point to the server.

How can we make both local and remote users' home directories accessible on the client?

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is to setup an autofs mountpoint in, say, /home2. Then set each user's home directory as /home2/machine/user. If you set autofs to mount machine:/home in /home2/machine, then you have what you want, because the local /home can be mounted as /home2/localmachinename. And you can of course configure autofs via NIS.

Answer (score 2):

If it's at all an option, I recommend making the “physical” location of each home directory something like `/net/$hostname/$username`, i.e., include the name of the server as part of the path. Then arrange for `/home/$username` to point to `/home/$(server-of $username)/$username`.

One possibility is to make `/home` a [union mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount) of all the `/net/*`.

Alternatively, you can make `/home` an automount point and set up the automounter to mount `/net/file-server/$username` for a NIS user or `/home.local/$username` for a local user.

Answer (score 1):

What we do is mount the server's home on /mnt/server/export/home, then on other machines symlink each user's home directory into the local /home. This can be maintained semi-automatically across machines with rsync.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify both local and remote mounts in an automounter config file (we use the `/etc/auto.home` file).

We have:

```
/etc $ ypcat auto.master
-hosts
auto.direct     --timeout=600
auto.home       --timeout=1800
```

and

```
/etc $ cat /etc/auto.home

localadmin        :/local/home/&
localuser         :/local/home/&

+auto.home
/etc $
```

Obviously very late, but hopefully useful for someone.